# How to format the return value of a generator parsing through an unknown depth JSON structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary, generator

### tl;dr:

why does this work ->
`dict(yield dict(name=new_key, url=d['url']).items())`

and this does not->
`dict(yield dict(new_key = d['url']).items())`

### The full code in question:

```py
import json

with open(".\OsintFrameWork.json", "r") as file:
    osintFramework = json.load(file)

from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def _flatten_dict_gen(d, parent_key, sep):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
       new_key = parent_key + sep + d['name'] if parent_key else d['name'] 
       if isinstance(d.get('children'), list):
           yield from flatten_dict(d['children'], new_key, sep=sep).items()
       else:
           # # This works
           yield dict(name=new_key, url=d['url']).items()
           # # The following doesn't work:
           # yield dict(new_key = d['url']).items()
    else:
        for k in d:
            yield from flatten_dict(k, parent_key, sep=sep).items()

def flatten_dict(d: MutableMapping, parent_key: str = '', sep: str = '-'):
    return dict(_flatten_dict_gen(d, parent_key, sep))

new_dict = flatten_dict(osintFramework)
clean_dict = {item[1]: value[1] for item,value in new_dict.items()}
__import__('pprint').pprint(clean_dict)
```

The data in question is from https://osintframework.com/arf.json

The question concerns the 2nd yield statement in `_flatten_dict_gen`

Why is it that I have to use a dict comprehension `clean_dict` to get the output I want

I've tried `yield dict(new_key = d['url']).items()`
I've also tried `yield {new_key : d['url']}.items()`

Generally any other way I've tried I get `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length x; 2 is required`

So boiling it all down:

#### How do I provide `new_key=d['url']` as keyword arguments to the outer dict() function

With cleaning:

```py
{'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Cryptome': 'http://cryptome.org/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Databases.Today': 'https://databases.today/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Weleakinfo': 'https://search.weleakinfo.com/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-WikiLeaks': 'https://wikileaks.org/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Other Media-Library of Congress: Digitized Newspapers - 1836-1922': 'http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Other Media-Library of Congress: Newspaper Directory - 1690-Present': 'http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/title
s/',
 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Other Media-TV Closed Caption Search': 'https://archive.org/details/tv', ....
```

Without cleaning:

```
{('name', 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Cryptome'): ('url',
                                                            'http://cryptome.org/'),
 ('name', 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Databases.Today'): ('url',
                                                                   'https://databases.today/'),
 ('name', 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-Weleakinfo'): ('url',
                                                              'https://search.weleakinfo.com/'),
 ('name', 'OSINT Framework-Archives-Data Leaks-WikiLeaks'): ('url',
                                                             'https://wikileaks.org/'),
```

Comment: when you use `dict(name=...)` or `dict(new_name=...)` then it treats `name` and `new_name` directly as name - it doesn't treats it as variable which have some value. You would have to use `{new_name: value}`

Comment: when I run your code with data from url then I get correct result - I can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

My version

- inside generator `_flatten_dict_gen` I runs yield with the same generator `_flatten_dict_gen` instead of exernal function `flatten_dict`
- inside generator I removed all `items()` and I can use `{new_key: d['url']}`
- it generates list of dictionares so I had to change code `flatten_dict` to convert this list to single dictionary

and now I don't need `clean_dict`

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
import requests

response = requests.get('https://osintframework.com/arf.json')
osintFramework = response.json()

#with open(".\OsintFrameWork.json", "r") as file:
#    osintFramework = json.load(file)

def _flatten_dict_gen(d, parent_key, sep):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
       new_key = parent_key + sep + d['name'] if parent_key else d['name']
       #print('new_key:', new_key)
       
       if isinstance(d.get('children'), list):
           yield from _flatten_dict_gen(d['children'], new_key, sep=sep)
       else:
           yield {new_key: d['url']}
    else:
        for k in d:
            yield from _flatten_dict_gen(k, parent_key, sep=sep)

def flatten_dict(d: MutableMapping, parent_key: str = '', sep: str = '-'):
    return {key:val for item in _flatten_dict_gen(d, parent_key, sep) for key, val in item.items()}

new_dict = flatten_dict(osintFramework)

pprint(new_dict)
```

`flatten_dic` can be also

```
def flatten_dict(d: MutableMapping, parent_key: str = '', sep: str = '-'):
    result = {}
    for item in _flatten_dict_gen(d, parent_key, sep):
        result.update(item)
    return result
```